# Grails: Delete relation Domain

Tags: grails, controller, relational-database

I want to asked about my project.
I Have Two Domain like this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look in the [GORM documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html). You have some ways to declare your relationship between classes, and depending on them the delete will be cascade or not.

This behavior is explained in **["6.3.3 Understanding Cascading Updates and Deletes"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#cascades)**.

> Whether it is a one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many, defining
>   belongsTo will result in updates cascading from the owning class to
>   its dependant (the other side of the relationship), and for
>   many-/one-to-one and one-to-many relationships deletes will also
>   cascade.

So you should consider declaring `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, to enable the cascading deletes.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User {
    // Group details should not be referenced here
}
class Group {
  String Name
  String Description
  GroupDetails gd
}

class GroupDetails {
    User user
    static belongsTo = [group:Group]
}
```

In this case if `Group` will have a child `GroupDetails` then when you delete `Group`, child entity(ies) will also be deleted.

Have a look at first example in grails docs: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

Also as Sérgio Michels there are more ways to make it work.

example: https://github.com/aprudnikovas/testGrailsOneToOneCascade

Comment: I have add the relation into my domain : 
class GroupDetails {
    User user
    static belongTo = [group:Group]
}

but when i try to delete, it get eror like this : 

Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):

Comment: Sorry small mistake: just fixed belongTo -> belongsTo